# Node: Requests inside requests Inside looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, asynchronous

I have the code below which makes a request to return all scheduled msgs before now and if there are some, it updates each document in the "scheduled" collection with a new date (increasing its value according to the repeat field), and if this document update is done, it inserts a new document on "msgs" collection.

The problem is I did an overly complicated code and it's inserting duplicated msgs at the end. I suspect the function "insertScheduledMsgs" is being called again before the async request to update the "scheduled" document inside the looping finishes, so the next time the function is called, the schedule document still have the old date.

How do I do it simpler and fixing this issue?

Below you can see the whole code:

```
function insertScheduledMsgs() {

request.get( {
    headers: { 'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token },
    url: urlApi + "scheduleBeforeOrAfterNow?msgsPosition=before"
}, function( error, response, body ){
    if ( !error && response.statusCode == 200 ) {

        results = JSON.parse( body );

        for ( let res in results ){
            let bodyMsg = "",
                bodySchedule = "",
                log,
                scheduleDate = (Number( results[res].date ) + ( Number( results[res].repeat ) * 60 * 1000)),
                date1 = new Date(results[res].date),
                date2 = new Date();

            bodyMsg += 'user=' + results[res].user;

            if ( results[res].media ) {
                bodyMsg += '&media=' + results[res].media;
            }

            bodyMsg += '&txt=' + results[res].txt;
            bodyMsg += '&time=' + results[res].time;
            bodyMsg += '&layout=' + results[res].layout;
            bodyMsg += '&boxes=' + results[res].boxes;

            bodySchedule += '_id=' + results[res]._id;
            bodySchedule += '&date=' + scheduleDate;

            if( date1.setSeconds(0,0) <=  date2.setSeconds(0,0) ) {

                request.put( {
                    headers: { 'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token },
                    url: urlApi + "schedule",
                    body: bodySchedule
                }, function( errorSchedule, responseSchedule, body ){

                    logs({
                        event: "date updated in scheduled msg",
                        date: new Date().getTime()
                    }, token);

                    if( date1.setSeconds(0,0) ===  date2.setSeconds(0,0) ) {

                        request.post( {
                            headers: { 'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token },
                            url: urlApi + "msgs",
                            body: bodyMsg
                        }, function( errorMsg, responseMsg, body ){

                            logs({
                                event: "scheduled msg sent to monitor / tv",
                                date: new Date().getTime()
                            }, token);

                            if ( (Number(res) + 1) === results.length ) {

                                insertScheduledMsgs();
                            }
                        } );
                    } else {

                        if ( (Number(res) + 1) === results.length ) {

                            insertScheduledMsgs();
                        }
                    }                   
                } );
            } else {

                if ( (Number(res) + 1) === results.length ) {

                    insertScheduledMsgs();
                }
            }
        };

    } else {

        insertScheduledMsgs();

    }
} );
```

};

Comment: are you sure your keys stored in `res` are numeric? if yes, why not use a numeric indexed for loop? if not, beware of conversions (have you tried to log `(Number(res) + 1)` with `results.length` to see when they match?)

Comment: The looping is working fine and the results.length is working as expected. The problem is with sync looping x async requests

Comment: I logged the values and, as I said, it works as expected... Maybe it's not the best implementation as you pointed out but It's not the cause of the bugs. The intent is to define the best way to work with requests and loopings once one is async and the other isn't. I never intented to make anyone debug my app for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with one of your values from the `for` loop being updated too quickly so that the value has changed between async tasks. If the case, you can try to wrap the code that uses these values into Immediately-invoked function expressions (IIFE) so that the values are kept inside. See those 2 following examples: the async task is simulated with a timeout. Without the IIFE all executions show the last value because the loop is already finished when it runs. With the IIFE the values are kept as they were when the code was reached. In your case probably `date1` is the guilty, but maybe `res` too (note that you must do the log inside the async sucess to see the problem):

```js
var arr = [{val: 'test1'}, {val: 'test2'}, {val: 'test3'}],
    i, l = arr.length, value;

for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
  
  value = arr[i];
  
  console.log('LOOPING i / value: ', i, value);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('WITHOUT IIFE WRAP i / value: ', i, value);
  }, 1);
  
  (function(_i, _value){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('WITH IIFE WRAP i / value: ', _i, _value);
    }, 1);
  })(i, value);
  
}
```